# Why is this series proven to converge with this approxiamation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given the series
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(n^4-1)} $$

and asked if it diverges or converges. Why does the integral
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx$$

Find it converges? I thought $$\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{1}{(x^2-1)}$$
so the lower function converging has no bearing on if the greater function converges?

Comment: 1. There are several criteria. 2. The bound $n^4-1>n^\frac{7}{2}$ also holds.

Comment: " I thought $\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{1}{(x^2-1)}$" Wait. What does this have to do with anything? Did you mean to write: "I thought $\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{x^2}{(x^4-1)}$..."

Comment: I thought that $$x^2/(x^4-1)$$ could be approximated by $$1/(x^2-1)$$

Comment: @user112167 well, $$\frac{x^2}{x^4-1}=\frac{1}{x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$ So I'm not sure what you mean by your above comment.

Comment: $\frac {n^2}{n^4-1}=\frac{1}{2 \left(n^2+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2 \left(n^2-1\right)}$ helps

Comment: Also
$$ \frac{n^2}{n^4-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{n^2+1}+\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{n-1}-\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{n+1}$$
so by telescopic sums
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n^2}{n^4+1} = \frac{3}{4}+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+1}<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4-1}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4-n^3}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1$$

What you are asking about is basically this:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4-1}\text{ converges}\Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\text{ converges}$$

since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^4-1}\cdot \frac{n^2}{1}=1$$

But we also have

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\text{ converges}\Leftrightarrow \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx\text{ converges}$$

by the integral test. We conclude

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4-1}\text{ converges}\Leftrightarrow \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx\text{ converges}$$